# Sci-fi novel, crash-landing, trying to escape planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book in the early 2000's in school. I only recall the plot vaguely. I do remember some people having crash landed on an alien planet. I believe it was a deadish place, no one around (perhaps post apocalypse). I recall it being flooded, maybe a swamp. When I think about it, it could have been a future Earth they landed on... my memory of it isn't great. They are trying to escape the place, but must repair the ship. Some of the people get into the the ship anyway later on and leave the others behind and the ships reactor melts/overheats or something during liftoff.

Not much to go on, I know, but someone might recognize the plot.

Comment: What sort of a planet is it? Single ecosystem? Multiple? Do they crashland in the jungle? In rolling meadows? Arctic snowfields? Desert? Bustling metropolis? Are there alien creatures? Plants? Humanoids? What sort of technology level do they have?

We have a list of questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to run through to elicit details. Also, I highly recommend taking the Tour, found at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Good question. I believe it was a deadish place, noone around (perhaps post apocalypse). I recall it being flooded, maybe a swamp. When I think about it, it could have been a future version earth they landed on... my memory of it ain't great :/

Comment: It's a reach but what about the beginning of *Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency*?

Comment: Some of the story elements ( crash landing, deserted planet, spaceship exploding during escape attempt while others watch from the ground ) are present in 'Polymath', one of John Brunner's Zarathustra Refugeer Planets series

Comment: I read a similar story but can't recall the title - IIRC there is a force in the planet is guiding the human survivors. The humans over time get more technically advanced until they can build a starship of their own, and finally get it launched only to have it blown up.

I seem to remember that the best and brightest were aboard the ship, and thus it was purposely blown up to remove them and put humans back to a less sophisticated civilization. I can't recall though if the "intelligence" had this plot all along

Answer (score 2):

[These Broken Stars](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1423171020) (Starbound #1) by Amie Kaufman and Meagan Spooner?

> It’s a night like any other on board the Icarus. Then, catastrophe strikes: the massive luxury spaceliner is yanked out of hyperspace and plummets into the nearest planet. Lilac LaRoux and Tarver Merendsen survive. And they seem to be alone.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and explain why you think this is the answer?

Comment: I've added a description for the book to hopefully save this answer.